# SD-Access -only VNIs and SGTs for policy enforcement within the fabric?

Tags: cisco, sdn

I’m currently getting myself up to speed with Cisco SD-Access. Particularly policy enforcement.

Am I right in saying that as SD-Access utilises VNIs and SGTs from which to enforce policies. Then only these can be used within the fabric to enforce policies and not source/destination IP addresses?

I’m guessing that you can (use source/destination IP addresses) but then that would negate a number of its benefits?

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The point of SD-Access is to be agnostic, using security at the endpoint/user layer instead of IP.

You should attend the Cisco SD-Access learning courses through their digital learning very helpful.

> https://digital-learning.cisco.com/#/search?query=sd-access

costs a few CLC for a years subscription.

Ideally, you want to ID all the endpoints and interactions with users groups/AD groups to assign the SGTs and limit your VNIs to roughly 3-4. however you need satisfy the minimum pre'reqs of specific version releases DNA/Switches/ISE and built out your underlay network before you can implement anythying.

There is quite a bit of planning involved before you can deploy.